# Google native map not working in ionic 3

Tags: angular, google-maps, cordova, ionic3

I have followed [Google native maps for ionic 3](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/google-maps/) but came across a typo

> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'BaseArrayClass' of null

Searched a lot on above error but could not find relevant answers.
I am using ***Angular4 with ionic 3 ***.

**app.module.ts**

```js
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { ErrorHandler, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicApp, IonicErrorHandler, IonicModule } from 'ionic-angular';

import { MyApp } from './app.component';
import { HomePage } from '../pages/home/home';
import { ListPage } from '../pages/list/list';

import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen';


import {GoogleMaps} from '@ionic-native/google-maps';
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyApp,
    HomePage,
    ListPage
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp),
  ],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  entryComponents: [
    MyApp,
    HomePage,
    ListPage
  ],
  providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    GoogleMaps,
    {provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler}
  ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

**home.html**

```html
<ion-header>
    <ion-navbar>
        <button ion-button menuToggle>
      <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
    </button>
        <ion-title>Google Maps</ion-title>
    </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>
    <div id="map"></div>
</ion-content>
```

**home.ts**

```js
import {
  GoogleMaps,
  GoogleMap,
  GoogleMapsEvent,
  GoogleMapOptions,
  LatLng,
  CameraPosition,
  MarkerOptions,
  Marker
} from '@ionic-native/google-maps';
import {
  Component
} from '@angular/core';
import {
  Platform,
  NavController
} from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {
  map: GoogleMap;
  mapElement: HTMLElement;
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, private googleMaps: GoogleMaps, public platform: Platform) {
    // Wait the native plugin is ready.
    platform.ready().then(() => {
      this.loadMap();
    });
  }
  ionViewDidLoad() {
    this.loadMap();
  }

  loadMap() {
    this.mapElement = document.getElementById('map');

    let mapOptions: GoogleMapOptions = {
      camera: {
        target: {
          lat: 43.0741904,
          lng: -89.3809802
        },
        zoom: 18,
        tilt: 30
      }
    };

    this.map = this.googleMaps.create(this.mapElement, mapOptions);

    // Wait the MAP_READY before using any methods.
    this.map.one(GoogleMapsEvent.MAP_READY)
      .then(() => {
        console.log('Map is ready!');

        // Now you can use all methods safely.
        this.map.addMarker({
            title: 'Ionic',
            icon: 'blue',
            animation: 'DROP',
            position: {
              lat: 43.0741904,
              lng: -89.3809802
            }
          })
          .then(marker => {
            marker.on(GoogleMapsEvent.MARKER_CLICK)
              .subscribe(() => {
                alert('clicked');
              });
          });

      });
  }
}
```

> Added a error screenshot

[image]

Comment: More information is required.

Comment: Hey, @AluanHaddad, added a description to my question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have the same problem in my application. I don't know if this is the best shape but for me resolve for now. (sorry, my english is not very good rsrs).

So try change this:

```
this.googleMaps.create(this.mapElement, mapOptions);
```

For this:

```
this.map = new GoogleMap(this.mapElement, mapOptions);
```

EDITED
I found a new solution for the problem. You need do downgrade the version of the @ionic-native/google-maps in package.json and execute npm update command.

Its possible that problem occours because a bug in the new version. The version that I use in my project is 4.2.1

Comment: @Marcelo Rafael, sure i will try your solution and will update related to same.

Comment: @Marccelo Rafael ,Error  went away but still map is not rendering on application tried with both of your methods

Comment: Issue cleared but I am getting the white screen. Might be some other issue

Comment: @BlueBells same here showing white screen, map is not rendering

Comment: How do you run your application? On device or browser?

Comment: @MarceloRafael  I am running my application on browser!

Comment: @md-5h04I3 you need run on device.

Comment: I run on Ios device still map not rendering